# How to create notification from fragment and navigate to other fragment on notificationclick

Tags: android, notifications, fragment

in my application I am having 1 activity and 5 fragments. I want to create a notification on button click in the first fragment(Homefragment). I dont have an idea about creating notification from a fragemnt. Then I want to navigate to ActionFragment when I tap on the notification. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on communicating between fragments here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

I've made a brief summary of how it would work:

What you would need is a interface that is declared in the first fragment and for the activity to implement it, and pass it to the fragment when it is created.

This way, the fragment can call the interface (mListener.notify()) which will then call the activity. The activity will then replace the current fragment with the new one you wish to open.